# HTML content in webpage automatically capsuled by CDATA tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have piece of Javascript code which shows ads on my website.
When I open my webpage in my office. The Ad doesnt show up. When I check the source of the webpage. It is automatically covered by CDATA tag.

Is it due to some adblocker.How to avoid this?

Comment: Probably a content filter of some kind, but can you post the relevant code, after it has been wrapped in the CDATA block.

Answer (score 1):

The CDATA tag is not the reason why your ad isn't showing.
Putting your Javascript in a CDATA tag is recommended according to the XHTML standards.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm

So the reason why your ad isn't showing must be something else.
Is there any code we can see to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> When I open my webpage in my office.

is it only happening @ your office maybe office proxies are stopping them